# I can't run two nested loops in order

Tags: python

```
for lop in range(0, len(kıloldum)):
    while len(liste) > sayac:
        nw = req.get(liste[sayac], headers=headers)
        nh = nw.text
        nb = btu(nh,"lxml")
        tablo = nb.find_all("div",{"class":"block-body js-replyNewMessageContainer"})
        for findwp in tablo:
            mesaj = findwp.find_all(string=kıloldum[lop])# bug
            if mesaj == []:
                pass
            else:
                ii.append(mesaj)
        sayac += 1
```

In this code, it pulls the links in the list according to the indexes, sends requests and digs. I have 2 elements in the list I want to add loops, but it doesn't work.

Comment: In order to help you please show a URL and its corresponding expected output

Comment: https://www.turkhackteam.org/forumlar/tht-yardim-merkezi.186/
in this forum i pull the topics in the help center and i get the people who post the most on the topics bulmak istediğim kişiler ise bunlar ["S.A.B.E.R!/","OBT is HeRYerDe"]

Comment: you can throw the request with headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"}